# Echo statements aren't being flushed properly?

Tags: php, buffer, flush

I've been trying to debug this code for hours now, but haven't been making any headway. My print statements are simply not working. Another question suggested I flush(), but it's not working.

```
echo 'this never prints';
flush();
flush();
flush();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the lack of a semicolon after the string a typo or is it like that in yout script?

Comment: is that your whole php script?

Comment: It's not a missing semi-colon. I was just using this as an example. But, that's essentially what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hm, what does an `var_dump(ob_get_level());` yield?

Comment: @Wrikken Nothing, but I was able to debug and found that ob_get_level() is returning a 3.

Comment: Ah, so, 3 `ob_flush()`es seem to be needed _before_ the output, or rather, you should find out why there are 3 output buffers active (they are _usually_, but not always, started with `ob_start()`).

Comment: @Wrikken wow, that did the trick! Thanks. If you can post as an answer, I will accept that.

Comment: @Rich Darvins: the `3` needed I said was wrong, but I fixed that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inside an outbut buffer, which you can check with `ob_get_level()>0`, you can flush contents with `ob_flush()`. If you want to break out of all outbut buffers, this is a quick oneliner to end them all:

```
while(ob_get_level()>0) ob_end_flush();
```

Possibly use `ob_end_clean()` instead of `ob_end_flush()` if you want to discard the buffer(s).

Answer (score 3):

I think you have the display_errors directive off. Check your php.ini file to see if this is the case.

Your code has a syntax error; you are missing a semi-colon after the echo statement. Any syntax error can only be seen in the browser if display_errors is on.

php.net on display_errors:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: The syntax error is most likely preventing the echo from ever executing. So yes... definitely turn on display_errors, dump up error_reporting, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "Hello Web!";
?>
```

In this simple script you can see some of the most used components of a PHP script. First off, PHP tags are used to separate the actual PHP content from the rest of the file. You can inform the interpreter that you want it to execute your commands by adding a pair of these: standard tags ""; short tags ""; ASP tags "<% %>"; script tags " ". The standard and the script tags are guaranteed to work under any configuration, the other two need to be enabled in your "php.ini"